# Howto handle umlauts in Logic App for export to csv

Tags: excel, csv, encoding, export, azure-logic-apps

I created a logic app to export some data to a *.csv file.

Data which will be exported contains german umlauts.

I read all the needed values into variables which are then concatenated and added to an array.

Finally I get an array of semicolon separated strings with the values in it.

This result will then be added to an email as file attachment:

[image]

All the values are handled correctly in the Logic App and are correct in the *.csv file but as soon I open the csv with Excel, the umlauts are not shown correctly anymore.

Is there a way to create explicitly a file with the correct encoding within the logic app and add the file to the email instead of the ExportString?

Or can I somehow encode the content of the ExportString-Variable?

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced in my environment and followed below steps to get correct output in CSV file:

My input is:

[image]

I have sent the data into CSV table as below and then created a file in file share as below:

[image]

Then when i open my file share and download the content from there i got different output as you got:

[image]

Then I opened my Azure Storage explorer and downloaded it as below:

[image]

When i open in notepad the downloaded file:

[image]

I get the correct output, try to do in this way

And when i save it as hello.csv and keep **utf-8 with bom** like below:
[image]

Then I get the correct output in csv as well:

[image]

Comment: thx for the hint! The problem is, that I would like to create the file with the correct encoding already in the logic app. Is there an action which does that? I was not able to find any.

Comment: check this [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/support-non-unicode-character-encoding#convert-payload-encoding)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have to apologize because I was not clear enough probably. Please check my updated question above.

Comment: Try to send the data into Excel file in logic apps then export it, this might work

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Not now since we are changing some other mechanisms. I'll update here as soon I have an update.