# "Create file" action in Logic Apps cannot show special characters

Tags: csv, type-conversion, azure-logic-apps, azure-files

To summarize shortly.
I need to transform a big xml file into a .csv file while also chosing specific fields of data.

1. I get a big xml file
2. I convert it to Json using a Compose action
3. I compose the fields I want from the json in a "Foreach"loop
4. I append it to an array variable (Within the foreach loop)
5. I use the "Create CSV table" action
6. I use the "Create file" action  from the "Azure file storage" and it successfully creates a .csv file that has the data I want.

These are my problems:

1.
[image: This is my "Create CSV table" action, you can see the name of the city "Göteborg"]

So I can see that the data going into the "Create file" action can successfully show the letter " Ö ".
However, this is how it looks when the final file is shown.
"GÃ¶teborg"

[image: GÃ¶teborg]

I cannot figure out how to make sure that the special letters will be shown. I've tried things like "base64ToSTring" but it's not accepted since the data is an array.

2.
The second issue I have is that my compose action is ordered alphabetically. So the final result I get in my file shows "City" infront of "FirstName" for example. I want "FirstName" to show first but after a lot of testing I cannot get it to order in the way I want.

---

Helpful for any tips on how to create this .csv file properly and in the way I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **`design`** in Logic apps is right (the problem is in local the way it is storing):

[image]

Output as been stored as it is :

[image]

But when downloaded it shows this way(problem with local not azure):

[image]

> Helpful for any tips on how to create this .csv file properly and in the way I want.

So, the alternative way is created a normal file and then save it as **`UTF-8 with BOM`** and then save it as name.csv. Refer this [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73800092/17623802) for the same:

[image]

Then Download the  file and then save it as:

[image]

then it will show the required format:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I feel stupid when I see that the data was correct in the end.
Helpful tip for something I can check myself in the future. You were correct that the file had the special characters when I opened it properly with the correct encoding.

Thank you!